# Can I upgrade 10.04 to 12.04.1 with the desktop image?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade, iso

I am running Ubuntu Lucid and would like to upgrade to Precise, using the *normal* ubuntu-12.04.1-**desktop**-...iso image.

So far I have tried upgrading with the CD but was not given the choice. Searching on the internet, I have found upgrading using the ubuntu-12.04.1-**alternate**-...iso image works, but I don't have great internet access.

Is upgrading from Lucid possible, with the `ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop` image?

Answer (score 1):

YES.

If was always intended that the point-release (**Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS**) would allow you to update from **10.04 LTS** to **12.04 LTS**.

However, if you simply run the install it will try to do a fresh install of **12.04.1 LTS**.

---

***If you insert the disk (or USB), does it not prompt you to upgrade to 12.04?***

(Sorry, I haven't tried this recently on 10.04 LTS.)

Comment: but there's no choice to upgrade from ubuntu 10.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LucidUpgrades  appropriate changes for ubuntu version is made:
Use this method if the system being upgraded is not connected to the Internet.

```
Download the alternate installation CD from http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Burn the ISO to a CD and insert it into the CD-ROM drive of the computer to be upgraded.

    If the ISO file is on the computer to be upgraded, you could avoid wasting a CD by mounting the ISO as a drive with a command like:

    sudo mount -o loop ~/Desktop/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-i386.iso /media/cdrom0

A dialog will be displayed offering you the opportunity to upgrade using that CD.
Follow the on-screen instructions.
```

If the upgrade dialog is not displayed for any reason, you may also run the following command using Alt+F2:

```
gksu "sh /cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```

Or in Kubuntu run the following command using Alt+F2:

```
kdesudo "sh /cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```